# ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"import":false}!

Tags: angular, firebase

```
"private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "angular2-flash-messages": "^3.0.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^5.0.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },


  "devDependencies": {

    "@angular/cli": "1.6.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

some one pleas help me i am new to angular and i am trying to build an application connected to firebase something went wrong and i don't know what i tried to change my bootstrap version different times and i need to work on angular 5 so i can't change it now can someone tell me what to do 
this is the error i am getting

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"import":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./src/styles.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `dead`
```

Comment: post your .angular-cli.json file.